# How does the AWS EC2 Auto Scaling synchronisation work automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

We started our wordpress blog some time ago with only one single EC2 Instance and a Multi-AZ RDS Database.

The traffic increased with heavy ups and downs (up to 1.500 user per minute), so we decided to use EC2 Auto Scaling. **Here is our problem:** Every time we changed some code, we have to create a new AMI for the Auto Scaling Group and terminate all instance so new instances will start with the new AMI Data.

**Is there a easy way to synchronize all instance automatically, when changing some code on one of them?** Perhaps Opsworks could to that but I haven't experience with this. I already searched a couple of days for a tutorial, but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: I think you should Docker, ec2 container and Continous Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your AMI to download the latest code on startup, so that you don't have to constantly update the AMI.

Or you could just use Elastic Beanstalk and let it manage all this stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to deploy changes to instances in your autoscaling group, I would recommend using Code Deploy.

Code Deploy integrates nicely with Autoscaling. If a scaling up event occurs, it will start a deployment to the newly launched instance and won't bring that instance into service in the AutoScaling group until the deployment has finished.

The deployments can be as simple as changing the code or else they can involve more thanks to Code Deploys deployment hooks.

Also you can have Code Deploy grab your code from S3, Github or CodeCommit.

Code Deploy is pretty easy to set up and the documentation is great:
[Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) [AutoScaling Integreation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html)